# Why would an AsyncTask's postExecute method not run in the UI thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a nested inner class that extends AsyncTask to run a db query in the background. In the post execute method I am calling a parent's method to update the view something like this

```
private class QueryRunner extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Cursor> {

  @Override
  protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... voids)
  {
     return getContentResolver().query(LeadContentProvider.buildUri(app.getEntityId()),new String[]{LeadContentProvider._ID},null,null,LeadContentProvider.LEAD_STATUS_DATETIME +" desc");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Cursor c)
  {
     onCursorLoaded(c);
  }
}
```

The onCursorLoaded method looks like:

```
private void onCursorLoaded(Cursor c)
{
  mPagerAdapter = new LeadDetailsFragmentPagerAdaper(getSupportFragmentManager());
  mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
  mPager.setCurrentItem(iIndex, false);
}
```

Most of the time this works fine - but some users have crashes with this stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from main thread of process
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1392)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:139)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:804)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:344)
at com.servicemagic.pros.activities.LeadDetails.onCursorLoaded(LeadDetails.java:205)
at com.servicemagic.pros.activities.LeadDetails.access$200(LeadDetails.java:25)
at com.servicemagic.pros.activities.LeadDetails$QueryRunner.onPostExecute(LeadDetails.java:196)
at com.servicemagic.pros.activities.LeadDetails$QueryRunner.onPostExecute(LeadDetails.java:170)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

So - why is the postExecute() method not called on the MainThread?

Comment: how do you define the inner class which extends AsynkTask? can you show code?

Comment: update the top code block with full AsycTask code.

Comment: I mean the whole hierarchy - parent class + inner class definitions. Is the parent class an Activity?

Comment: The parent class extends from FragmentActivity in the compatibility library.

Comment: @harmanjd use `super.onPostExecute(null);` in your `onPostExecute()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what @hovanessyan is getting at is that it is not safe to assume that the Fragment your AsyncTask was talking to when it launched may not be the same instance as when it finishes executing.  Android may pause or even terminate the Fragment while the AsyncTask is running.  That would explain why the problem is intermittent.  It is only happening to users when their Fragment has been paused or destroyed and recreated.

This issue is discussed [in this article](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/14/handling-progress-dialogs-and-screen-orientation-changes/).  If you read items 2 and 3 in the article you will see how to address it.  You are responsible for saving and restoring state as part of your Fragment life cycle.  See android documentation of [Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article. I think I understand better what is probably going now - but let me state it here to make sure.

In the activity lifecycle of: onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy() if you create an AsyncTask in onCreate() or even later, and the Activity is paused via onPause(), then when onResume() is called again, it will be on a main thread, but NOT NECESSARILY the same main thread use to create the activity originally. 

In that case when the AsyncTask finishes it's onPostExecute() method may show this behavior.

Comment: By using the pattern in the article mentioned - that won't happen because when the activity is paused it prevents the callback from happening until the activity is resumed at which point you are running in the new thread context. Is that your understanding?

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding.  Complicated, huh?

Comment: Yeah kind of.

Anyhow - based on your prompting here with the links I changed my approach to using the *LoaderManager* and a *CursorLoader*. The LoaderManager takes care of this lifecycle and manages when the result is delivered correctly and I avoid the problem described in my question. I hadn't done so before because for this particular activity I didn't want the cursor to reload if the db changed. But I subclassed the CursorLoader to avoid the registration of content observers.

Answer (score 2):

the [onPause() - onResume() loop](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Android_Logcat-Activity-Starts.jpg) does not go through onStart(). If you need this to be executed on the start of your Activity, put it in onResume(). You always go through onResume().

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with my question.